# Javascript URL regex to start with just www. or http(s)://

Tags: javascript, regex

Thanks for your help!

I'm looking to convert urls in a string to `<a href="url">url</a>` using javascript.

I have the following regex:

`/https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)/gi`

which seems to work pretty good for any url starting with either `http://`, `https://`, `http://www.` or `https://www.`.

However, it doesn't work for urls starting with just a `www`: `www.url.com`

How can the regex be modified to work with the following:

```
http://
https://
http://www.
https://www.
www.
```

Thanks again for your help! Have a great day!

Comment: urls starting with `www.` would be urls that request from server the current file was loaded from ... `www.` would suggest the url is poorly formatted, unless the server had a folder/file named `www.*` - I guess you could `(https?:\/\/)?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use alternation

```
(?:https?:\/\/(www\.)?|www\.)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/=]*)
```

```js
const regex = /(?:https?:\/\/(www\.)?|www\.)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/=]*)/i;
const strs = ['http://example.com','https://example.com','http://www.example.com','https://www.example.com','www.example.com','example.com']

strs.forEach(str=>{
  console.log(str, '  |   ', regex.test(str))
})
```

[`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/a1DY2P/1/)

If you want `example.com` also to match then you can make `(?:https?:\/\/)?` optional

```
(?:https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/=]*)
```